# How to filter, group and plot data using crossfilter and dc.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dc.js, crossfilter

I have the following data and a bar chart of its counts. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisguzman/y9xt2/). I would like to filter the dimensions, so that in the bar chart I only have Alyssa and Bob. I have tried different variations of creating filtered variables using `.filter()` function and filtering the chart directly. The main problem appears to be the `XDimension.group().reduceCount` because apparently "group methods consider only records that satisfy every filter except this dimension's filter." I am lost. Help appreciated.

```
var data = [{
    Owner: "Alyssa",
    ID: "A"
}, {
    Owner: "Alyssa",
    ID: "A"
}, {
    Owner: "Alyssa",
    ID: "A"
}, {
    Owner: "Alyssa",
    ID: "A"
}, {
    Owner: "Alyssa",
    ID: "B"
}, {
    Owner: "Bob",
    ID: "A"
}, {
    Owner: "Bob",
    ID: "A"
}, {
    Owner: "Bob",
    ID: "C"
}, {
    Owner: "Bob",
    ID: "C"
}, {
    Owner: "Bob",
    ID: "C"
}, {
    Owner: "Bob",
    ID: "C"
}, {
    Owner: "Bob",
    ID: "C"
}, {
    Owner: "Bob",
    ID: "D"
}, {
    Owner: "Joe",
    ID: "A"
}, {
    Owner: "Joe",
    ID: "A"
}, {
    Owner: "Joe",
    ID: "D"
}, {
    Owner: "Joe",
    ID: "D"
}, {
    Owner: "Joe",
    ID: "E"
}];

var ndx = crossfilter(data);


var XDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.Owner;
});
var YDimension = XDimension.group().reduceCount(function (d) {
    return d.Owner;
});
dc.barChart("#Chart")
    .width(480).height(300)
    .dimension(XDimension)
    .group(YDimension)
    .centerBar(true)
    .gap(56)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(XDimension))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .xAxisLabel("Market Developer")
    .yAxisLabel("Unique Counts")
    .elasticY(true)
    .xAxis().tickFormat(function (v) {
    return v;
});
dc.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to filter the data prior to adding it to the crossfilter?

```
data = data.filter(function (d) { return d.Owner !== "Joe"; });
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
```

I am currently working on a similar problem and this was a temporary solution. I tried filtering the dimension like so:

```
var filtered = XDimension.filter(function (d) { return d !== "Joe"; });
var YDimension = filtered.group().reduceCount(function (d) { return d.Owner });
```

When I print out "filtered", I see that the dimension was properly filtered. However, when the chart is drawn, "Joe" was still in the data set.

Ill post back if I find a better solution..

Comment: I actually I figured that out yesterday. I used very similar approach. You are on the right track. I will write my solution which works as soon as I get some free time. Simply, make `XDimesnion=ndx.dimension(function(d){if(d.Owner=="Joe" || d.Owner=="Bob") {return d.Owner;}})`. Thats all you gotta do. Then, yo can use the group functions normally and it will work.